# Outer Left Join on Includes Rails 3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join

Is there a way to perform .includes and specify an outer left join.

Originally:

```
@post = Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.spam = ?", false).where(:id => params[:id]).first
@comments = post.comments
```

The desire is to mimic:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@comments = post.comments.where(:spam => false)
```

Except using includes would perform it in an eager loading fashion (if say I had multiple posts).

Thanks for the help in advanced.
Justin

Comment: I did something like this, here is how i achieved it:

[Stack Overflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441012/any-possible-way-to-add-parameters-to-on-clause-on-include-left-joins-on-rails/16551544#16551544

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  has_many :non_spam_comments, :through => :comments, :conditions => {:spam => false} 
  has_many :spam_comments, :through => :comments, :conditions => {:spam => true}
end
```

Then, you'll be able to do:

```
@posts = Post.where(:user_id => current_user.id).includes(:non_spam_comments)
@posts.each do |post|
  post.non_spam_comments.each do |comment| 
    // Some comment operation
  end
end
```